# Set request timeout in jetty-runner

Tags: java, jetty

I'm running a Jetty web app on AWS. I start the application in following way.

```
nohup $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Denv=$1 -jar $LIB_PATH/jetty-runner-*.jar --config $CONF_PATH/jetty.xml --classes $CONF_PATH --port $app_port $DIST_PATH/app*.war &
```

Is there a way to set request timeout when using Jetty runner ? How to find default value ? I'm using jetty 8.1.4

Comment: [Jetty 8 is now EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).  Consider upgrading to Jetty 9.

Comment: Will upgrade in next release. But for now, how to do this ? For that matter, how to do this in Jetty 9 ?

Comment: Since Jetty 9, I stopped using jetty-runner, the jetty-distribution is actually less work and easier to setup than jetty-runner now.